# Left Join? zeros are not returned

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to get the result of this query to include all the flavor.model and sum the quantity of the ones ordered. It does work except it does not show anythign from the flavor table when nothing was ordered. I though left join would include all the item from the left side?

```
select 
   flavor.id, 
   flavor.model, 
   IFNULL(SUM(orders.quantity),0)as ORDERED
from
   orders
LEFT JOIN 
   flavor 
   ON orders.model=flavor.model
where
        orders.orddate >= '131006' 
    and orders.orddate <= '131013'
    and orders.buyer<>'****@gmail.com'
GROUP BY 
    flavor.model
```

Comment: The "left side" of the query is the table *before* the join statement.

Comment: Be careful with the grouping... it smells odd.

Comment: YOu are right, grouping by flavor.id is better but doesnt resolve the missing records

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` as your left column, `orders` is your reference table, hence you won't get `flavour` values which aren't found.

Comment: In addition the where clauses must be made into join clauses (`ON ...`). Otherwise they will make the join behave as an inner join as they are referring the table having the 'optional' rows.

Comment: Even trying the RIGHT JOIN I am unable to get any of the NULL values. Tried parenthesis before the ON and included the WHERE statement but no luck.